# DELIMITER | ó //

Tags: mysql, trigger

He leído que "DELIMITER" se utiliza cuando hay diferentes sentencias a cumplir en algun procedure, trigger, etc. Sin embargo, he visto que lo escriben de 2 formas distintas:

Ejemplo 1:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
    DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;  
    UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
  END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar | o usar //?

Answer (score 1):

No hay diferencia, ambas son válidas.

---

Se usa `DELIMITER` para indicar que a partir de aquel momento, el delimitador será un carácter distinto de `;`. Esto se hace cuando vas a definir triggers, stored procedures o funciones, donde hay distintas sentencias en los que aparece `;` y no quieres que se ejecuten inmediatamente, sino que se cojan como un todo. De este modo, defines un conjunto de instrucciones que se ejecutarán todas juntas.

Yo generalmente he visto usar `$$` porque es una combinación lo suficientemente visual como para que resalte en el código y uno se percate rápidamente de ella. Dicho lo cual, la [referencia oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) indica que:

> puede ser cualquier carácter o conjunto de ellos. Conviene evitar el uso de la contrabarra (`\`) porque es la secuencia de escape de MySQL.